# Docker in Fedora 37

Tags: docker, fedora

I have recently installed Fedora 37 (KDE) and trying to install Docker. I have followed the instructions in https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/fedora/. Now when I try to do "sudo docker run hello-world" I get timeouts. Error below

Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

I am not behind and proxy, I did disable IPv6 because I was having some slow internet problems following https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comm...on_super_slow/

I did see people having similar issues, but most of them are behind a proxy which I am not, and since I am new to Fedora (Linux) I am not sure if it has something to do with the IPv6 being disabled.

Update: I have tried docker desktop on the same machine under windows and its working fine, no issues. I still can't figure out why its complaining in Fedora 37

Comment: edit your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to set `"max-concurrent-downloads": 1` that should help with timeout. by default it tries to download 3 at a time.

Comment: so I didn't have the file, created it, restarted docker using systemctl, but still the same :(

Comment: This question is not related to programming and thus off-topic here. It might be on-topic on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try Podman instead of Docker and it was still the same.

What worked for me with Podman was I added values in the hosts file in /etc folder. I did `nslookup` for docker.io and got 3 IP addresses and added them there. For all the subdomains within docker.io I used the same IP address in the hosts file. Maybe this would have worked with Docker as well, but didn't further experiment with it. Sample values from my hosts file looks like this:

34.194.164.123 registry-1.docker.io 
52.1.184.176 auth.docker.io 
18.215.138.58 index.docker.io

Hope this helps others as well. Still not sure why I had to manually add them there.